# How can I dump internal files of Perl?

Tags: perl

```
print Dumper \%main::;
```

tells me there's such file:

```
      '_<perlmain.c' => *{'::_<perlmain.c'},
```

How can I dump it?

I tried these ways but none work:

```
my $typeglob = *{'::_<perlmain.c'};
print "@$typeglob\n";

print @{'_<DynaLoader.c'};
my @arr = @{'::_<xsutils.c'};
print "@arr";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly extract the source for these files if the code itself is not compiled in or provided as a module.  To read these files, you would need to fetch the Perl source bundle from CPAN.

You can, however, extract the `miniperl` which is used part of the creation of the core Perl, but is missing core module auto-load data; read the perldoc or manpage for `ExtUtils::Miniperl` for details.

Comment: The array @{$main::{'_<'.$filename}} (aliased locally to @dbline via glob assignment) contains the text from $filename, with each element corresponding to a single line of $filename. Additionally, breakable lines will be dualvars with the numeric component being the memory address of a COP node. Non-breakable lines are dualvar to 0.

Comment: This is quoted from here: http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.1/lib/perl5db.pl#___top

Comment: Perl cannot print the contents of files that do not exist -- I cannot find any of `perl.c`, `perlmain.c`, `mro.c`, `DynaLoader.c`, `perlio.c`, `universal.c` or `Dumper.c` on my system outside the Perl source distribution.  Additionally, I don't believe the Perl 5 debugger can be used to debug the C portions of the Perl 5 reference implementation.

Comment: If you *do* want to read the Perl sources, I recommend you download the sources from CPAN or browse the latest source online at the [Perl 5 Git repo](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tree).